# Анимация элемента в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Очень нужен совет как выполнить данную задачу.
Вся сложность заключается в том, что круг который меняет содержимое на каждом слайде скорее всего должен быть один т.к траектория его движения должна быть видна:
от 1 слайда ко 2му: движение от верхнего левого угла к нижнему правому и т.д
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как понять - *траектория его движения должна быть видна*?

Comment: При перелистывании от 1 слайда ко 2му: движение от верхнего левого угла к нижнему правому
от 2 к 3: круг движется по горизонтали влево и немного вверх. 
Т.е задать анимацию перемещения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Анимировать перемещение можно с помощью [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_transitions.asp).

Посмотрите пример.

```js
var circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

function gotoStep(step) {
  const currentStep = circle.getAttribute('data-current');
  if (currentStep !== undefined) {
    circle.classList.remove('step' + currentStep);
  }
  circle.setAttribute('data-current', step);
  circle.classList.add('step' + step);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: top 2s, left 2s;
}

.circle.step0 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle.step1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: calc(100% - 44px);
}

.circle.step2 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="gotoStep(0)">step 0</button>
<button onclick="gotoStep(1)">step 1</button>
<button onclick="gotoStep(2)">step 2</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle step0" data-current='0'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: я заметил что на самые сложные вопросы которые никто не может ответить отвечаете всегда вы браво .Поставил плюсь

Comment: @Demon__ANT если это не сарказм, то спасибо)

Comment: Хороший пример :) попробую его в слик слайдере

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko нет конечно (без сарказма) я впольне серьезен.

Comment: Решение помогло. Подскажите как реализовать доп.функционал в slick slider'е, чтобы при автопроигрывании слайдов, тоже менялось положение круга (решение не обязательно и так уже очень выручили, просто направление дальнейших действий)

Comment: @stiv Там должно быть событие, которое вызывается при смене слайда. Вот в этом событие устанавливайте нужный вам класс.

Comment: Вроде бы должно быть так, считываем значения дата атрибута и потом помещаем в класс. Но что не так?
http://prntscr.com/kznf42

Comment: @stiv Вы не удаляете предыдущий class. Также, вы уверены, что в data-current есть необходимое вам значение?